# Linear systems of equations and vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, systems-of-equations

I'm looking for references that explicitly (and in an accesible way: *-I come from engineering-*) handle the connection between solving a linear system of equations and the abstract geometry involved.

Comment: Why did you delete half a body of text? The answer below no longer makes sense.

Comment: It appeared to me that it was the right thing to do, since it was just a "computation artifact" that was originating an apparent contradiction in my theoretical understanding. I'm really not sure about what the procedure in those cases is... You're right and seem more experienced in stack exchange so: should I re-edit it back ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation between rank and nullity is  $\;\dim\ker A+\dim\operatorname{Im}A=\dim \mathbf R^{62}$, the hypotheses imply $\dim\ker A=11$.

As for the result with Maple, you should check your data: if $\dim \ker A=11$, the solutions should depend on $11$ parameters, not $10$.

Comment: Added maple file, solution has (as far as I can see) 10 parameters.  Are there any implicit assumptions for "if dim kerA=11, the solutions should depend on 11 parameters, not 10 ?"

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have Maple. For the number of parameters, it is only the definition of dimension: in a space of dimension 11, you need 11 coordinates. However, as I do not know your linear system, maybe your problem has other assumptions that you didn't mention?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Turning the coefficient matrix from floating point to rational arithmetic gives expected results. I'm editing the question to leave only the reference request. Do you happen to have any to recommend (specific connection (pref w examples) between linear systems and spaces) ?